# Visual basic 6 program in windows 10 still using mdb after it has been deleted

Tags: ms-access, vb6, windows-10

I am using a visual basic 6 program in windows 10 which uses an mdb file. The problem is that if I delete or rename the mdb file the program somehow still uses a copy of the database. I can't find this copy anywhere, it appears to be a ghost file. The problem only exists in Windows 10.

Comment: The mdb file is included in setup files and installed locally in the application's folder.

Comment: Even if I uninstall the application, restart the pc and reinstall it without the default mdb (excluded from package and deployment wizard in vb6) the fresh installation still use the previous mdb!!! How can this happen? The .exe uses related path to find the mdb (.exe folder).

Comment: You can use a utility like [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see the file(s) that the application is using.

Comment: I use process monitor but the only I see is the process of the exe. Inside properties I saw in the tab "threads" that use 3 threads with msjet 40.dll

Comment: I search the pc for *.mdb but nothing found

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you were looking at, but on my machine Process Monitor shows me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Q0o.png).

Comment: Gord Thompson  you are right... I used Process Explorer... With Process Monitor I found it... C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\database.mdb. It seems that created on setup a copy.

Comment: It is a shame... you are wrong misters...  I did not ask "Why do files get placed in “C:\Users\<username>AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files(x86)”?" I was looking for this path as an answer, not a question... you are completely confused

Answer (score 3):

Your 32 bit app stored data somewhere where it is no longer allowed too (probably program files). All changes will be directed to `"C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\VirtualStore"`

This allows programs that wouldn't otherwise be allowed to run on Windows Vista to Windows 10 to run without being an administrator.

This also applies to writes to the System registry key.